# How to Hide the filters dynamically?

Tags: yadcf

I have a switch to go to edit mode that is supposed to show the filters.

I am able to show them, but I do not know how to hide them when I quit the edit mode.

I tried the following but it is not working :

```
$('#myTable').find('.yadcf-filter').hide();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all yadcf filters are being wrapped with a container that got the `.yadcf-filter-wrapper` class, the following should do

```
$('.yadcf-filter-wrapper').hide();
```

p.s

I'm yadcf author

Comment: Thank you Daniel, that's what I ended up doing (or more exactly `$('[id^=yadcf-filter-wrapper]').hide()`)

Comment: You are welcome, you better use my selector since it should be faster